# Conditionally apply css to parent element

Tags: html, css

I have the following dynamic markup:

```css
#navigation li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="selected">Start page</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="display: none;">Logic</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Your name</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="display: none;">Caller</a></li>
</ul>
```

Where list items need to be hidden the application injects `style="display: none;"` into the anchor tag which leaves a blank space due to the padding on the parent li element. When there is a large list and multiple hidden links the spacing between the list items gets messed up.

Is there a way in css to check if anchor has `style="display: none;"` and define the css to remove the padding top and bottom from the parent `li`?

Any way to achieve this without jquery in css?

Comment: Can you set `display: none` to `li` directly instead of the links?

Comment: An alternative would be, provided you have access to the necessary CSS, to only style the `a`-tags, and remove all styling from the `li`-tags. This way, if another system *hides* the a-tag, no spaces should be visible.

Comment: @Rafael no i don't, it's injected by the application into the a tag

Comment: @Yoshi thats what i've done in the mean time.

Comment: @adam78 if you control the CSS, then maybe apply margins and paddings to the links instead of list items? Would that help in any way or is it problematic?